# Determining Java XPATH for multiple Nested Namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:A xmlns:ns2="u:a">
    <payload>
        <ns2:B xmlns:ns2="u:m:n:b>
            ....... lots of stuff......
```

Abbreviated all the stuff beneath it since I just need to figure out the xpath for that ns2:B

What would be the XPATH for this, right now I'm trying:

```
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("//ns2:A/payload/ns2:B");
    nodeList = (NodeList)expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
    System.out.println(nodeList);
```

But it's not picking up anything.

I also tried just getting the root A element with

```
\\ns2:A
```

As the xpath but that did not work either.

Comment: Use `NamespaceContext` to define two namespace prefixes for the two different namespaces in play.  Ignore the fact that `ns2` is used twice in your XML; choose two different namespace prefixes for the different namespaces.  Namespace prefixes do not have to be the same as used in the XML; namespace URIs themselves are all that matter. See duplicate link for further details.